# Writing an R Function That Returns Another Function

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I want to write a function that will output a new function. I've tried the following function, which didn't work.

```
fxn1 <- function (x) {
  if (x > 5) {
    fxn2 <- function (y) {
      y * 3
    }
  } else if (x <= 5) {
    fxn2 <- function (y) {
      y + 2
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this type of thing in R?

Comment: You need to return the generated function in addition to assigning it within the generating function (or leave the assignment `fxn1` thus implicitly returning the generated function instead of assigning it).

Comment: What do you mean by it "didn't work"? You seem to be returning funcitons but you are assigning to a variable so they are returned invisible. If you want to return a function, you can't give it a name, it will be anonymous. With your code this will work `fxn2 <- fxn1(10); fxn2(5)`. For simplicity, remove the `fxn2 <-` part from the function itself since that variable won't exist after the function returns.

Comment: See the [function factories](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html) section of Advanced R by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: I voted to close this question down, as it points to an non-existing problem

Comment: All you have to do is to put `fxn2` as the last instruction in your function.

Comment: A bit of advice:  **never** write "didn't work."   **Always** post the output you got as well as the desired/expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me to be working. What behavior are you expecting?

```
fxn1 <- function (x) if (x > 5) function (y) y * 3 else function (y) y + 2

fxn2 <- fxn1(0)
fxn2
#> function (y) y + 2
#> <environment: 0x000002b44fbd5528>
fxn1(1)(3)
#> [1] 5
fxn1(10)(3)
#> [1] 9
```